# What's the best way to use Regular Expressions on a text file?

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, optimization

Since Regular Expressions seem to accept only string, the most common way to search a file is either by reading it to a single string or by reading each line in turn.
The problem is that with big files you either hold a huge string in memory or killing the GC with very large amount of strings that are created, used and left for garbage collection.
Does anyone know of a better way to access this problem?

Comment: Did you ever experience a `killing the GC`? How did you do it?

Comment: too* (now I have to type 11 more characters...)

Comment: So what problem did you experience with the GC? Or do you just fear them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'best' way depends on your needs.

And you won't 'kill' the GC with a large number of strings that quickly. Test/verify your assumptions.

- When your problem is line-based, read the lines one-by-one. Prefer `File.ReadLines()` over `File.ReadAllLines()`.
- If your problem spans the whole file (`RegexOptions.Multiline`, maybe including line-breaks in the patterns), you will have to read it into 1 string. Use smaller files if it becomes a problem.
- In all cases, use common sense and/or a profiler.

Comment: +1, also for reading line by line he could use the `IEnumerable<string> File.ReadLines` method.

Comment: It was not added yet so I write the comment, however in the time I finish writing the comment and post it I found you already added it :)

Comment: @Henk: I don't see how the `Multiline` option is relevant.  All it does is change the behavior of the string/line anchors (`^` and `$`), and you don't even know if the OP is using them.

Comment: @Alan: That's why the sentence starts with _if_.

Comment: @Henk: The reason I brought it up is that there's a persistent, rogue meme out there that goes: *If the target string is multiline (meaning it contains one or more line breaks), you must specify the `Multiline` option* (or whatever your current regex flavor calls it).  I think it's important to at least comment on it whenever it shows up (or seems to), if only for the sake of any regex neophytes who might read this.

Comment: @Henk: Thanks. Indeed, after posting the question I noticed that the amount of string instances is not such a big issue. However, performance-wise, it's always best to pass the file as a single string - until you start dealing with very large files.
I will accept you answer - mainly for the "common sense" part.
In my case, I'll probably have to consider the size of the file and in case of a large file I will read chunks of it and in the worst case miss a few hits (very low probability). for my needs it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process a full file which doesn't fit the memory comfortably (as in a few KB of data), you probably should look into "proper" parsing. There are many good [parser generator tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) around, my favorite one is the [GOLD Parsing System](http://www.devincook.com) by Devin Cook, but others such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) are very as well.

The regex engine is not a plain DFA, it does backtrack in some cases. I assume that this is the reason why the regex cannot be applied to a sequence of characters; since efficient random access is needed holding the data in memory seems to be the obvious solution.

Comment: Good advice in _some_ situations. The OP is not very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Either load line by line, or load portions of the file. If you want you Regex to span line breaks, use Multiline option

Comment: @Henk: Here, I believe, is an example of the rogue meme in action.  Akran, please read the comments under [Henk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827591/whats-the-best-way-to-use-regular-expressions-on-a-text-file/6827651#6827651).